# App Crash when comes back from Sleep

Tags: signalr, azure-mobile-services

I am using **xamarin** for crossplatform app development . We have used asure mobile service to connect with database . Basically This application is for chatting purpose so we have used *SignalR* with .NET Framework.When app comes from sleep after some duration like 60 seconds it get crashed. Is there any way to connect back using *SignalR*.Issue seems with *SignalR*. Where exactly do I need to update code at client side or server side .
Client side code

```
public class SignalRClient
    {
        private  static string CONNECTION_URL = "http://";
        private static TimeSpan CONNECT_TIMEOUT = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30); 
        private readonly  HubConnection _hubConnection;
        private  readonly IHubProxy _chatHubProxy;
        private static string AuthToken = "";
        public  string UserID;
        public event SignalRConnectionStateChangedDelegate SignalRConnectionStateChangedEvent;

        public SignalRClient(string authToken)
        {

            AuthToken = authToken;

            _hubConnection = new HubConnection(CONNECTION_URL);
            _hubConnection.Headers["xauth"] = AuthToken;
            _hubConnection.TransportConnectTimeout = CONNECT_TIMEOUT;
            _hubConnection.Error += ex =>
            {
                if (SignalRConnectionStateChangedEvent != null)
                {

                    _hubConnection.Stop();
                    SignalRConnectionStateChangedEvent("Error :" + ex.Message);
                }
            };

            _chatHubProxy = _hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("ChatServer");

        }

        public async Task Connect(string UserID)
        {

            if (_hubConnection.State != ConnectionState.Connected)
            {

                try
                {
                    await _hubConnection.Start();

                    _hubConnection.StateChanged += (connectionState) =>
                    {
                        if (SignalRConnectionStateChangedEvent != null)
                        {
                            SignalRConnectionStateChangedEvent(connectionState.NewState.ToString().ToLower());
                        }
                    };
                } 
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var message = ex.Message;
                }
```

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: You can check the code now

Comment: "application crashes" is a bit vague. Post an exception with the stack trace etc.